# Problem while exporting mongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB version  1.6.5

One of my collection has 973525 records.

when I try to export this collection mongodb exports only 101 records.

I can't figure out the problem .

any one knows the solution for it.

Comment: please, describe that how you implement export function

Comment: mongoexport -c collectionName -d databade -o /filePath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like corruption. If your server has not shutdown cleanly that could be the cause. Have you had system crashes where you didn't do a repair?

You can try to do a dump with mongodump --dbpath if you shut down the server first.

Note: MongoExport/Import will not be able to restore all the data since json can't represent all possible data types.